# How to prevent CSS from being auto-appended to bottom of the head element

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

A group of volunteers has created a single/multi-select web component using StencilJS: https://github.com/NothingAG/adg-components

For this web component, Shadow DOM is not enabled so that developers can override/customise styles.

Now we want to hand it over to the client so they can use it in their project. They do it like this:

```html
<script type="module" src="/build/adg-components.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="/build/adg-components.js"></script>

<adg-combobox
  id="hobbies"
  name="hobbies"
  label="Please select your hobbies"
  optionslabel="Hobbies"
  multi="true"
  lang="de"
></adg-combobox>
```

What they experience though is that because the Shadow DOM is not enabled, the CSS is auto-attached to the very bottom of `<head>`, after any other styles:

[image]

This makes is very hard to override specific styles. Is there a way to prevent that? For example, it would make much more sense in our case that the styles are added right after `<script type="module" src="/build/adg-components.esm.js"></script>`, so any following `<style>` would take precedence.

One other workaround I can think of is to remove the styles altogether when running `$ npm run build`, and then let the client import the styles manually. But this doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *For this web component, Shadow DOM is not enabled so that developers can override/customise styles.* Use `::part` for that, that's no reason to ditch shadowDOM.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about `::part`? I don't know what this is, actually. Any references to the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Shadow DOM is turned off, Stencil attaches the CSS to the `head` element, **before the first `link` element**.

Here is the relevant line of code that does this:
https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/0cd139b6a0e17c6b0916d8b0fb3e943a523f4a2f/src/runtime/styles.ts#L79

So all you need to do is have at least one `link` element in the `head` and the CSS will be inserted in the correct document order so that you can override the styles.